# Making a Dodger game in ruby using Gosu

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I'm new to programming and Id like to make a Dodger type game using the Gosu library. I don't know if this question completely adheres to Stack Overflow's rules but I haven't seen anything to the contrary.

Currently I know how to make window pop up where you can print some text an move it around, that's where i got the idea that all i need is some obstacles the player can avoid and some mechanism to detect if my text(Ill probably just use a "^" or something to simulate a spaceship.) has been hit.

I can't seem to find any tutorials or descriptions on how I should go about this, basically what I'm asking is for any helpful information on how I should go about it or where I could find a tutorial or something similar.

Comment: Everything you need is in https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Ruby-Tutorial

Comment: Here are the Stack Overflow rules applying to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - item number 4 shows that it is unfortunately off-topic to ask for links to tutorials or other off-site resources. The rest of the question is too vague/broad. You can still ask questions about your project - the best questions are about specific problems you face when writing your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I will keep that in mind in the future. Also thanks Hitham, i tought i could find something like that at GitHub, i just have no idea how to use GitHub... find it seriously confusing. I guess i would have to get more acquainted with it sooner or later anyways so why not now :P